# How to keep double quotes with Sprintf?

Tags: php

Well, I'm try to create some like that:

```
$mutation = 'mutation {
  companyCreate(
      name: "'. $name .'",
      description: "'. $description .'"
  ) {
    idCompany
    name
  }
}';
```

But sometimes, the variables may have double quotes and can broke my mutation code.

So, I tried to use `sprintf`:

I have a variable like that:

`$myVar = '{description: "%s"}';`

And I'm using the `sprintf` function to replace the text in this way:

`sprintf($myVar, "This is the description");`

But some time I have to add this text `sprintf($myVar, "The \"awesome\" day");`

But, the `sprintf` print this:

`{description: "The "awesome" day"}`

But I need to se it: 
`{description: "The \"awesome\" day"}`

What is your best solution to do it?

Comment: What is the intended use of this `$mutation` string?

Comment: For my unit test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
sprintf($myVar, addslashes('The "awesome" day'));
```

It outputs

```
{description: "The \"awesome\" day"}
```